# SelectedItem not shown in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am using MVVM in a WPF application with C# and got a problem binding a ComboBox correctly.

This is my ComboBox line in the XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Repository.Models}" SelectedValue="{Binding Repository.SelectedModel}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
```

This is the interesting part of my Repository:

```
 class Repository : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //init MVVM pattern
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Model> _models;
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Models
        {
            get
            {
                return _models;
            }

            set
            {
                _models = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Models");
            }
        }

        private Model _selectedModel;
        public Model SelectedModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedModel;
            }

            set
            {
                _selectedModel = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedModel");
            }
        }
```

This is the interesting part of my Model class:

```
 abstract class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //init MVVM pattern
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
```

So when I select/change different items of the combobox a DataGrid that is binded to Repository.SelectedModel.Parameters does update just as i want it  to.
Because of that I know, that the binding does work!

When I restart the application and debug into my Repository, I see that there is a SelectedModel (deserialised on startup) but the ComboBox stays blank. The DataGrid though does show the right data.

So the binding itself does work, but the binding to the ComboBoxLabel somehow fails.

I tried a lot of things like switching between SelectedItem and SelectedValue, between Binding and Binding Path, between IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem true and false, but nothing worked so far.

Do you see my mistake?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Here is the interesting part of my MainWindowViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //init MVVM pattern
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private Repository _repository;
        public Repository Repository
        {
            get
            {
                return _repository;
            }

            set
            {
                _repository = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Repository");
            }
        }
```

And here is my App.xaml.cs where I init my DataContext:

```
   //init point of app
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;

        //gets fired as the app starts
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            //create the ViewModel
            mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

            //create the mainWindow
            var mainWindow = new MainWindow();        
            mainWindow.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;

            //show the mainWindow
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is no path `Repository.Models` (assuming your main model doesn't have `Repository` property of type `Repository`). You set binding context to `Repository` instance and then `ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}`. How does it even display something? How do you set `DataContext`? Do you set `ItemsSource` manually in code?

Comment: Added the missing code. The path DOES exists as you can see now.

Comment: Assuming that you've changed `SelectedValue` to `SelectedItem` is setter of `SelectedModel` ever called? Any binding errors in the output window? Is it all done from single thread?

Comment: Yes, right away when I start the app and afterwards every time when I select something in the combobox -> just as it should. Also my DataGrid updates correctly. But the Combobox still keeps blank after the start although my SelectedModel is se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I restart the application and debug into my Repository, I see that there is a SelectedModel **(deserialised on startup)** but the ComboBox stays blank. The DataGrid though does show the right data.

Looks like the deserialization is the problem.

You have a selected item which was *deserialized*. That means that a new `Model` instance was created which has a `Name` of whatever, and `Properties` that are whatever. And you have a list of `Model` instances in an `ObservableCollection<Model>` which are displayed in a ComboBox.

And you assure us that at least sometimes, you have `ComboBox.SelectedItem` bound to `SelectedModel`, though for some reason the code in your question binds `ComboBox.SelectedValue` instead. That's not going to work. Here's how `ComboBox.SelectedValue` would be used:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Repository.Models}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Name"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedModelName}"
    />
```

...and you would have to have a `String SelectedModelName { get; set; }` property on your viewmodel. The `Name` property of the selected `Model` would be assigned to that by the `ComboBox` when the selection changed. But you don't have `SelectedModelName`, and you don't want it, so forget about `SelectedValue`.

Back to `SelectedItem`. The `ComboBox` gets the value of `SelectedModel` from the binding, and tries to find *that exact object* in its list of Items. Since *that exact object is not in that list*, it selects nothing. There is probably an item in `Repository.Models` that has the same name and has identical `Properties`, but *it is not the same actual instance of the `Model` class*. `ComboBox` doesn't look for an identical twin of the value in `SelectedItem`; it looks for the same object.

`SelectedModel.Properties` works in the `DataGrid` because the `DataGrid` doesn't know or care what's in `Models`. You give it a collection, it's good.

So: If you want to deserialize a `SelectedModel` and have it mean anything, what you need to do is go ahead and deserialize, but *then* find the *equivalent* item in `Repository.Models` (same `Name`, same `Properties`), and assign that actual object instance to `SelectedModel`.

You may be tempted to overload `Model.Equals()`. *Don't*. I've done that to solve the same problem. The resulting behavior is not expected in C# and will bite you, hard, and when you least expect it, because you are invisibly altering behavior that happens in framework code. I've spent days tracking down bugs I created that way, and I'll never do it to myself again.

Comment: Thank you very much, you opened my eyes. As you said I looked for the model with the same name as my deserialized selectedModel via a LINQ expression. Works great.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I faced some strange behavior. That is right after initialization it's blank, but you can select and it shows up, I'm wondering if you can give me some idea, thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090923/why-this-uwp-combobox-can-be-blank-after-initialization-but-works-fine-for-selec

Answer (score 1):

Try SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue in ComboBox.

Comment: @selmaohneh please show code where you tried it. That is at least part of your problem.

Comment: Instead of SelectedValue I wrote SelectedItem. Not that big deal, I wrote about my tries, didn't want to type them down all, since they're trivial.